# URLEncoder to encode only certain UTF-8 characters not all in a string

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

Suppose I have a url

String url = "[http://myweb.com/page1?param1=Financiële](http://myweb.com/page1?param1=Financi%C3%ABle) resultaten&param2=consùmer"

I want to URLEncode.encode(url, "UTF-8") this string. I want only while space and ampersand (&) to be encoded keeping (ë and ù) intact. So Final URL should be

[http://myweb.com/page1?param1=Financiële%20resultaten%27param2=consùmer](http://myweb.com/page1?param1=Financi%C3%ABle%20resultaten%27param2=cons%C3%B9mer)

How to achieve this in java?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind that you should use `URIEncode` only for encoding query parameters. So what you will encode is after '?' character.

Another problem with your question is that, you don't actually want to encode the whole query. So there is no method for you to encode it for some specific characters. Then your question can be converted into something like 'How can I replace some characters with some other characters'. Therefore, you may want to use `replaceAll` method for the characters that you want to change, or `indexOf` method if you want to encode characters seperately then you should merge.

A way to start using replaceAll method is something like:

```
String query = "page1?param1=Financiële resultaten&param2=consùmer";
query.replaceAll("\\s+","%20");
```

Then the string becomes "page1?param1=Financiële%20resultaten&param2=consùmer".